# when a div is loaded with image using jquery other div inside it are vanishing.Why this happens?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Hi i loaded a div with Image by using jquery Other div inside it are vanishing.
here is the css

```
.d1
    {
     position:fixed;
     z-index:999999;
    }
.d2
    {
     position:absolute;
     background:green;
    }
```

this is the line i used to load image in **d1**

```
jQuery(".d1").html(jQuery("<img>").attr("src",eee));
```

with css

```
<div class="d1">
 <div class="d2"> 
 Text
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function ($){
 jQuery("img").click(function($) {
 var eee = jQuery(this).attr('src');
 jQuery(".d1").html(jQuery("<img>").attr("src",eee));
 });
 });
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

when i run this i can't able to find the text from **d2**
but when i run this without script means the text is visible from **d2**.
i don't know whether is this a jquery problem or error.**d2** is vanishing when i click any image but it shouldn't vanish upto my point.before clicking any image **d2** is there i can see this differences using firebug.Do anybody know what the exact problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you are **setting** the content of `.d1` using the `.html()` method. therefore everything that was in there before, gets **replaced**.

Comment: Thanks for your understandable answer to me:)Gun Foo. before i don't know why it's happening now i got it.

Comment: again some problem if i click image **d1** is appended with that image but if i click another image again it's appending with another image.It's keeps increasing b'coz we are appending right.is there a way to append only one image that is current image?

Comment: only append if there is no image in `.di` otherwise `.replaceWith()` the image.

Comment: Ya i tried **replaceWidth** but it replacing the whole div **d1**. like Background color and other image from **d2** are replaced.is that possible to append a css property there?any other clue?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`jQuery(".d1").html(jQuery("<img>").attr("src",eee));`

with this line:

`jQuery(".d1").append(jQuery("<img>").attr("src",eee));`

note the `append`, using `html` you are replacing the content `html` of `.d1`.

Answer (score 1):

With `.html()`, you are replacing the current HTML with you `img`.

Use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add your image after the `div`

**OR**

Use .prepend() to add your image beforethe `div`

Comment: Someone know why the link to `prepend` is not work? Anyway info here : http://api.jquery.com/prepend/‎

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">Text</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($){
        jQuery("img").click(function($) {
            var eee = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            jQuery(".d1").append(jQuery("<img>").attr("src",eee));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Remove the script from inside **div**, it's a good practice anyway.

Comment: The reason is that he is replacing the content html content of d1. I agree that the script should be outside the html code, but this will not solve the problem. Use `.append` to add the image after the d2 div.

Comment: any particular reason to place script after **div**? or for clear writing are you suggesting that?

Comment: @Littlefool More than a "complete solution", this was a recommendation for better coding practice and completion of the highest rated answer. Btw `append` is part of my code anyway if you look closer, so what you're suggesting already lies there ;).
@raj the way I feel it is the `div` is your "view" in this case so you should control it separately from the <script> which you might call the "controller". It's just for the abstraction, separating presentation from what's happening under the lid. Of course the code would work anyway both ways.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I overlooked it.